# How to create a quick expand to a Keno UI window with icon changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

I cant seem to figure out why kendo won't work. I am trying to create a custom button on the kendo window to expand the window to 75% and then back to 34%.

VIEW

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("stockLineWindow").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "windows" })
    .Title("Stock")
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable(resizable => resizable.Enabled(true))
    .Visible(false)
    .Scrollable(false)
    .Actions(actions => actions.Minimize().Maximize().Custom("arrow-chevron-right"))
)
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var stkWrapper = $("#stockLineWindow").data("kendoWindow");

var expand = stkWrapper.wrapper.find(".k-i-arrow-chevron-right");
expand.click(function (e) {
            stkWrapper.setOptions({
                width: "75%"
            });
            $(this).removeClass("k-i-arrow-chevron-right");
            $(this).addClass("k-i-arrow-chevron-left");
        e.preventDefault();
    });


var contract = stkWrapper.wrapper.find(".k-i-arrow-chevron-left");
expand.click(function (e) {
    stkWrapper.setOptions({
        width: "34%"
    });
    $(this).removeClass("k-i-arrow-chevron-left");
    $(this).addClass("k-i-arrow-chevron-right");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Two things are happening here:

1. when the window opens i am able to run the expand. But the DOM resets after a setOption and continues to show '>' instead of changing the class.
2. After it expands it never retracts even when i change the javascript to this:

   ```
    var stkWrapper = $("#stockLineWindow").data("kendoWindow");

    var expand = stkWrapper.wrapper.find(".k-i-arrow-chevron-right");
    expand.click(function (e) {
        if (stkWrapper.options.width <= "75%") {
           stkWrapper.setOptions({
           width: "75%"
       });
       e.preventDefault();
   } else {
       stkWrapper.setOptions({
           width: "34%"
       });

   }
   e.preventDefault();
   });
   ```

It happens once and never happens again. Unless i reload the window. All i want to do is a simple expand and contract button on the Kendo window. I'm not sure how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$(wnd.wrapper).on("click", ".expand-button", function() {
    let $btn = $(this),
        wnd = $("#wnd").data("kendoWindow"),
        width = "31%";

    if ($btn.hasClass("k-i-arrow-chevron-right")) {
        width = "75%";
    }

    wnd.setOptions({
        width: width
    });

    if (width == "75%") {
        $(wnd.wrapper).find(".expand-button")
            .removeClass("k-i-arrow-chevron-right")
            .addClass("k-i-arrow-chevron-left");
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oFAqA/2)

One interesting thing about the [`setOptions()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-setOptions) method is that it recreated the whole window again, including the button. So after `setOptions`'s execution, the `$btn` variable reference is broken, you have to *find* the button again. That is why I put an `if` changing the icon only if the new width is `75%`, otherwise the icon will created as it's initial state again.

Comment: You are brilliant! Now i am trying to have that button change icon when the user manually resizes. Might be a media query.

Comment: @NeoSketo remember that the Window widget haves [`resize`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#events-resize) event. Perhaps you can do that in there.